# Appcelerator/Titanium - Call variable from within function

Tags: javascript, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have some code as below, which gets the current location and then creates a variable with that information. I would like to use that variable outside of the function but so far everything I've tried has failed. The alert below works if it's within the function, but as soon as you put it outside it's blank. I've also tried creating global variables in alloy.js but that didn't seem to work either. I know this is very simple but need some more ideas :)

```
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
if (e.error) { 
    alert('Error: ' + e.error); 
} else { 

    var params = {
        latitude: e.coords.latitude,
    };

    return params;

} 
});



alert(params);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to Titanum but a basic javascript question.
`params` is a local variable (inside the getCurrentPosition). You can create a global scope like this:

```
var coords;

Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    if (e.error) { 
        alert('Error: ' + e.error); 
    } else { 
        coords = {
            latitude: e.coords.latitude,
            longitude: e.coords.longitude,
        };
    } 
});
```

But keep in mind: coords might not be set straight away because it could take a bit until the getCurrentPosition function is finished or has the data.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you. I added `alert(coords);` after the function and it still comes out blank, I also tried latitude and coords.latitude

Comment: Like I said: getCurrentPosition takes a bit to produce the result. If you put the alert straight after the function it will be called almost at the same time it checks for the position and shows an empty box. You need to change the logic of your code so it will work with the values when the callback is done

Comment: Ahhhh...thank you I finally understand now....a timeout helped! Sorry for the basic questions :)